# How to get count of unread emails from yahoo and hotmail

Tags: c#, email, outlook, yahoo, hotmail

I want to get count of unread emails in yahoo and hotmail inbox, for gmail there is a simple way to do this i.e. via Gmail inbox feed. My question is how to get unread msgs count in hotmail and yahoo? Please tell me all alternatives.

For now I only want to get count of unread, no need to get whole msgs.
I require a C# solution.

Comment: why did you tag this question with outlook, do you want to use outlook for that?

Comment: not desktop outlook, I tagged this as outlook because now live and hotmail is rebranded to outlook (outlook.com)

Answer (score 1):

for mail accouts with POP server, you can use a pop implementation like http://hpop.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -2):

use Gmail API:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/

Here is a wrapper for C#:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmail-api/

As I remember, in Gmail API you have an method to return an array of unread messages.

Comment: This question is not about Gmail, its about Yahoo and hotmail. I know a lot of solutions for gmail.